# Repairing electrical oven - appears to be broekn thermostat, but is not

Tags: repair, appliances

I have Whirlpool Bauknecht oven, bought via Ikea a few years back. Sadly I lost the receipt so the customer service won't help me ...

Following problem: The oven heats, but does not turn of the heating elements at the set temperature. The oven turns itself off at a highter temeprature, apparently some back up temp. switch. I assumed that the thermostat is broken and baught a replacement, with the same serial number as found on the old thermostat. However, after exchanging the old vs. the new thermostat (always removing the fuses before working on the oven!), the problem persists. I also since checked the old thermostat with a cup of hot water and a continuity tester, it appears to be working.

When exchanging the thermostat, I accidently pulled one of the wires from the little lamp (that's in series with the thermostat) and I had to reconnect it with a terminal strip. Since the issue is apparantly the same as before my 'repair' that does not appear to be it.

I also continuity tested the installed, new thermostat. This also appear to work. All in all, the oven bahaves as if the thermostat were short circuited.

I've looked for wiring diagrams to understand better where the problem could lie, but had no success.

My oven:
Manufacturer: Whirlpool/Bauknecht
Type: FXZM6
Series Number: 852315201500

What's likely wrong with my oven? How to confirm and fix?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the wires may be shorted together. When it comes right down to it the thermostat is just cutting or energizing power like a light switch so if the wires were to touch farther down the line the switch would be worthless. I would physically trace all the wires in the circuit to make sure they aren’t bridging the thermostat. You could take both wires off the heating element and see if you have continuity with an ohm meter. Continue up the line until you get OL and your short should be there.

Comment: sorry, I wasnt clear enough: I tested the now installed thermostat in situ without disconnecting the wires. So if there is a short, I would have detected it (unless the shortcircuit is only is specific positions of the switch for the oven program ...).